# pyCharm and django admin

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I'm trying to run a Django admin page in PyCharm.

I've created a test project with an empty test app and a simple model.

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    email = models.EmailField()
```

As I open `127.0.0.1:8000/admin/` I can see the admin page. However, not only I don't know where the password is (I don't recall setting any password so far) but trying to login will crash the server with this error:

> OperationalError at /admin/
>
> no such table: auth_user
>
> Exception Location:
> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py
> in execute, line 451

Why? And how can I set a password?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In a terminal, `cd` into your project root and type `./manage.py syncdb`. This will create the initial tables.

When it gets around to creating the `auth_user` table, it will ask you to create an admin user, and set a password on it. These are the credentials you need to log in to the admin interface.

Edit: For those using Django 1.7+, the correct command to sync your database initially is now `./manage.py migrate`. Keep in mind that this will *not* prompt you to create an admin user automatically. In order to bring up the prompt, run the command `./manage.py createsuperuser`.